# Rails 3: 3 models and routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have projects, which have tickets, which then have comments.  I believe the code for the model associations are correct?

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ticket, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :project
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :comments, :through => :tickets
end
```

Before I click the button, the route is:

```
http://localhost:3000/projects/7/tickets/16
```

When I click the submit button, the route changes to

```
http://localhost:3000/tickets/16/comments
```

How do I get it to read:

```
http://localhost:3000/projects/7/tickets/16/
```

after submitting a new comment to show up on the `tickets/:id` view?

When I submit and and create the comments on the ticket object, it gives an active record error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#create
Couldn't find Project without an ID
```

using this controller:

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @ticket = @project.tickets.find(params[:ticket_id])
  @comment = @ticket.comments.new(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to project_ticket_path(@project, @ticket)
  else
  end
end
```

New to rails but it has to be with the model association or routing...

My routing links...

```
Kaledoscope:ticket_taker Evolution$ rake routes
    project_tickets GET    /projects/:project_id/tickets(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tickets"}
                    POST   /projects/:project_id/tickets(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"tickets"}
 new_project_ticket GET    /projects/:project_id/tickets/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"tickets"}
edit_project_ticket GET    /projects/:project_id/tickets/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"tickets"}
     project_ticket GET    /projects/:project_id/tickets/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tickets"}
                    PUT    /projects/:project_id/tickets/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"tickets"}
                    DELETE /projects/:project_id/tickets/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"tickets"}
           projects GET    /projects(.:format)                              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"projects"}
                    POST   /projects(.:format)                              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"projects"}
        new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"projects"}
       edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"projects"}
            project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects"}
                    PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"projects"}
                    DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"projects"}
    ticket_comments GET    /tickets/:ticket_id/comments(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                    POST   /tickets/:ticket_id/comments(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
 new_ticket_comment GET    /tickets/:ticket_id/comments/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
edit_ticket_comment GET    /tickets/:ticket_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
     ticket_comment GET    /tickets/:ticket_id/comments/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                    PUT    /tickets/:ticket_id/comments/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                    DELETE /tickets/:ticket_id/comments/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
            tickets GET    /tickets(.:format)                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tickets"}
                    POST   /tickets(.:format)                               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"tickets"}
         new_ticket GET    /tickets/new(.:format)                           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"tickets"}
        edit_ticket GET    /tickets/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"tickets"}
             ticket GET    /tickets/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tickets"}
                    PUT    /tickets/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"tickets"}
                    DELETE /tickets/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"tickets"}
               root        /(.:format)                                      {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"index"}
```

Comment: Run `rake routes` in your project. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you need to make a slight change.  Where you have `@ticket.comments.new`, you should have `@ticket.comments.build(params[:comment])`.  For example:

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @ticket = @project.tickets.find(params[:ticket_id])
  @comment = @ticket.comments.build(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to project_ticket_path(@project, @ticket)
  end
end
```

Build will build a new comment with the `ticket_id` set to the `id` of the parent.  If you do a `new`, it won't properly set the `ticket_id`, so it won't be able to redirect to the route given since `@ticket` and `@comment` won't be associated.

From the Rails documentation:

`collection.build(attributes = {})`
Returns one or more new objects of the collection type that have been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, but have not yet been saved.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that build method.  That does the association for the two models?

Comment: Thanks Sean! I used more than one level for nested routing giving me routes like project_ticket_comments_path.  Trying to find a solution that doesn't do that type of nesting.  I know I need to check my model associations, something along the lines of project model: has_many :comments, :through => :tickets